# Dynamically Add Title to a popover element - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, popover

I'm trying to set a title to my popover object on my local project. I've already included these :

- bootstrap.css v4.2.1
- jquery.min.js v2.2.0
- bootstrap.min.js v4.2.1
- popper.min.js v1.11.0

I had a simple button

```
<i id="Dualstack-Pvt" class="fa fa-info-circle float-right" data-toggle="popover" data-content=""></i>
```

When I click on that `i`,  I want to set the `title` + `content` *dynamically*

so I did these :

```
console.log("title = ", response.name); // it is working 

$('.fa-info-circle#'+objectName).attr("title", response.name);
$('.fa-info-circle#'+objectName).attr('data-content',JSON.stringify(response));
```

---

## Result

`title` seems to be dynamically added to the DOM.

But the popover seems to have a hard time rendering it correctly.

[image]

Comment: whats the value of objectName?

Comment: Whats the output of response.name

Comment: @Keith : `title =  Dualstack-Pvt` is the return of this line `console.log("title = ", response.name);`

Comment: @sid : `console.log("objectName = ", objectName);` return `objectName =  Dualstack-Pvt`

Comment: @sid : I updated the comment.

Comment: assuming there are no JS errors, whats the actual function that is making this happen. Something is corrupting it

Comment: @Keith: no error in the console;

Comment: @Keith : I am not sure where to place this line `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();`- should it be in a function() ? or out side of any function() ?

Comment: @Keith : do you think that might have something to do with this ? maybe race condition ?

Comment: Just trying to rule out all possibilities. It works just by itself

Comment: I'm assuming data-content is what shows in the bubble from your code. So when you add response.name to data-content what shows? Also, does it even add a title at all as attribute from the line above that code?

Comment: Without seeing more of your code its difficult to see where anything is going wrong. I've read the question several times and at first the issue seems to be adding the title WITH the content to the data-content attribute and getting it to pop up correctly. But it doesn't look like you're trying to do that at all in your code. Your code looks like you're trying to set the title attribute and the data-content attribute separately and are succeeding in doing so. We can't see if your title attribute is working, but your popover displays a stringified object as I would expect. What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change

`$('.fa-info-circle#'+objectName).attr("title", response.name);`

into

`$('.fa-info-circle#'+objectName).attr("data-original-title", response.name);`

However, please take a look into the documentation on a proper way of refreshing the contents of the popover.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this

```
$('.fa-info-circle#'+objectName).attr('data-content',JSON.stringify(response.name));
```

or

```
$('.fa-info-circle#'+objectName).attr("title", response[0].name);
```

Comment: The content is not a problem. It seems to render fine, as you can see in the screenshot I shared. The problem is the title;

Comment: No @sid this is wrong 

`$('.fa-info-circle#'+objectName).attr("title", response[0].name);` -- why [0] ? 

My console is working fine.